# Javascript syntax Help on sorting function

Tags: javascript

### Code

```
function SortByID(x,y) {
    return x.id - y.id;
}

function SortByName(x,y) {
    return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
}
```

### Problem Description

I am new to Javascript and I am learning how to make a sorting algorithm. I have a few questions regarding the two functions above.

1.Can you please explain the line of code below to me in words?

```
return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
```

2.What does the question mark in the above code mean?

3.what doest the "? 1: -1" and "? 0 :" means?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good site to explain these syntax :)
[Sorting Tutorial](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C8D00514FA4)

Thanks for the answers above.

These functions are for the Javascript's inbuilt .sort() function to sort accordingly.

if you have:

```
var obj_to_sort; //in json format
```

Then we can simply sort this variable by entering:

```
obj_to_sort.sort(SortByName); //or
obj_to_sort.sort(SortByID); ...etc
```

and for each SortByXX function (which is declared by yourself), it should take in two parameters like below:

```
function SortByID(x,y) {
        return x.id - y.id;
}

function SortByName(x,y) {
    return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
}
```

There are three scenarios:

if -1(or neg) is returned, x will come before y;

if 1(or pos) is returned, x will come after y;

if 0 is returned, x = y;

And by using .sort() function, it will automatically sort according to your algorithm.

and for:

```
 return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
```

it means:

- if x = y ; output 0
- otherwise, if x > y ; output 1
- otherwise, output -1.

? means output,
: means otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a ternary operator. It's a short way of writing if else statements.

```
((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
```

Is the same thing as.

```
if ( x.Name == y.Name ) {
    return 0;
} else {
    if ( x.Name > y.Name ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Another way to read it would be like this.

```
(( Condition ) [IF TRUE] 0 [IF FALSE] (( Condition ) [IF TRUE] 1 [IF FALSE] -1 ));
```

Comment: It’s not exactly like an `if` statement — it’s important to understand that t ternary operator evaluates to a value — so you can use it anywhere, even when you’re not returning something.

Comment: This is very true. However, you have to return them to something whether it's a variable or return statement...which was confusing at first. It definitely takes some time to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is known as the conditional operator (or ternary operator) it is a shorthand way of an if then else block, bearing this in mind we have:

> 1.Can you please explain the line of code below to me in words?

If x.Name equals y.Name return 0 otherwise if x.Name is greater than y.Name return 1 otherwise return -1

> 2.What does the question mark in the above code mean?

The '?' operator takes the form:

```
(expression evaluating to true / false) ? (if true expression) : (if false expression)
```

> 3.what doest the "? 1: -1" and "? 0 :" means?

See answer 2 for syntactic meaning. In this context returning 0 means the values are deemed equal, -1 means the first value is less than the second and 1 means that the first value is greater than the second.

Comment: check your final return; should be `-1` not `0`

Answer (score 1):

1 . That means literally:

```
    if(x.Name == y.Name) return 0;
    else{
      if (x.Name > y.Name) return 1;
      else return -1;
    }
```

2. and 3. The key is in ternary operator syntax.
Expression `A ? B : C` means "check if `A` is true and if it is true then expression value is `B` otherwise `C`"

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorting function which explains how two items will be sorted when compared to eachother

a return value of greater than one will flip the order of the items

1. part of the ternary operator
2. part of the ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

This type of statement is found in other programming language. It is shorter version of the if else statement. For example

```
if(condition){
statement1} else {
statement2}
```

can be written as

```
condition ? statment1 : statement2
```

In your case, two condition are being tested and the equivalent if else statement would be

```
    if(x.Name == y.Name) {
    return 0;
} else {
     if(x.Name > y.Name){
    return 1;}
    else {
    return -1;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
```

If `x.Name` is the same as `y.Name`, return `0`; otherwise, if `x.Name` is greater than `y.Name`, return `1`; if both those statements are false, finally return `-1`.

Bonus note: use `===` instead of `==` so that you compare both type and value, not just value.

Answer (score 0):

This makes heavy use of the ternary operator. The ternary operator is like a `if` statement in one line.

```
expression ? result if true : result if false
```

So that

```
3 == 3 ? "yes" : "no"
```

Returns "yes". Now basically this is a sort function. Sort functions want you to give them a number that represents a comparison between two items. If the items are equivalent, you return 0. If not, you return 1 or -1 to determine which one is bigger.

This expression basically checks if the names are equal. If they are, it returns zero. Otherwise, there is another condition which will return 1 if `x.Name` is "bigger" than `y.Name`, or -1 otherwise.

This could be expressed as the following:

```
if (x.Name == y.Name) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    if (x.Name > y.Name) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  return ((x.Name == y.Name) ? 0 : ((x.Name > y.Name)? 1: -1));
```

In other words

```
 if(x.Name == y.Name){
      return 0;
 }
 else{
    if(x.Name > y.Name){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
     }   
 }
```